# User can't right-click SQL Azure database in SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

I've done the following on my SQL Azure instance:

1) Add a new login
2) Create a new user on my database from that login 
3) Granted db_datareader to that user on that database

I can use that user to connect through SQL Server Management Studio, and I can expand the "Databases" node in the Object Explorer, but once I try to right-click the database to select "New query", the whole UI freezes for about 30 seconds.

I can connect and do the same thing with the db_owner, and it works without a problem.

Is there some other role/right I have to give to the user?

Comment: What about through the Azure portal?

Comment: And what about right click on the server, and choose new query. It's the same? Can you try through sqlcmd?

Comment: Right click on the server -> "New query" works, and it opens the correct database.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following statement on the Master database and that should do the trick

CREATE USER LoginName FROM LOGIN LoginName

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the following permissions to that new login :

```
GRANT CONNECT TO YourNewLogin;

GRANT SELECT TO YourNewLogin;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alberto, try to avoid self-promotion in your posts as per the [guidelines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). You should add your website to your profile, which is available through every post you make, if you'd like to show your affiliation.

Comment: That didn't work. Like I describe above, the user can already connect, but once connected he can't right-click the database he has the DB_READER role on.